# Gremlin Console for Windows error "The most significant bit.."

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

Seems like Gremlin Console not working for Windows:
I downloaded the latest Gremlin console and run the bin\gremlin.bat file. seems like after connecting (as in the below commands) and running a simple remote command (*g.V(123).count()*) I'm getting an error:

```
The most significant bit should be set according to the format
```

This is the commands I run:

```
PS C:\Users\L836423\Downloads\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.7-bin\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.7\bin> .\gremlin.bat

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.jcabi.manifests.Manifests).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
==>Configured my_gremlin_dns.com/55.222.88.111:8182
gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [my_gremlin_dns.com/55.222.88.111:8182] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
gremlin> g.V(123).count()
The most significant bit should be set according to the format
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin>
```

Comment: could you please include the stacktrace? also, is Gremlin Server on azure also version 3.4.7? i'm mostly sure that this error is a graphbinary serialization error which makes me wonder if Gremlin Server has graphbinary configured properly as a serializer on the server.

Comment: unfortuatly it doesn't wait for my answer to print stacktrace, it just printing the whole info right after I run the command, and I'm back in "gremlin>" cli. I'm running using docker janusgraph/janusgraph:latest from the official : https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker . I have no idea how to check the gremlin server version. But, if I run the same command using another conatiner as a gremlin cli docker container, it works. for examle: docker run --rm  -e GREMLIN_REMOTE_HOSTS=myJanusDns.com -it janusgraph/janusgraph:latest ./bin/gremlin.sh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when the server you are connecting to does not support the string serialization of Graph Binary used by newer versions of TinkerPop. You will need to use an older client. Find out what level the server supports and use the corresponding Gremlin Client version.

Specifically, the change went into the Gremlin Client as part of the 3.4.3 release. Your server needs to be at least at that version to use a Gremlin Client >= 3.4.3

With 3.4.3 the default serializer for the Gremlin Client was changed to be GraphBinary. It is possible you could also edit the settings in the YAML file read by the client to use a different serializer.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, using client 3.3.11 made it work on windows cmd.. thanks :)